# How to auto-map attributes from Java Map to POJO class attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pojo, spring-rest

I am working on a spring boot application and developing a spring rest (PATCH) service.

I have a situation where I need to map the data received on the PATCH request in a HashMap from the front end to a java POJO class.

The attributes that I need to map in the POJO class are present in the key of the Hashmap. We need to iterate through the map and associate the value of the key in the map to the POJO class attribute.

What is the best way to do this? I know that there is a very leborious way where I manually check each key in the map and associate the corresponding value to the appropriate setter in the POJO class. But this is extremely cumbersome if the number of attributes in the POJO class are many in number.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Code snippet

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public Project editProject(@RequestBody Map<String, String> project, @PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Inside editProject() API ");

        if(project == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for(String key: project.keySet()) {
            logger.info("Keys passed for update ==> Key(" + key + "): Value(" + project.get(key) + ")");
        }

        Project projectRec = null;

        try {

            logger.info("updateProject() :: Before save :: ");

            projectRec = projectService.updateProjectInfo(project, id);

            logger.info("updateProject() :: After save :: Saved successfully ::: ", projectRec.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }

        logger.info("Leaving createProject() API");

        return projectRec;
    }

public Project updateProjectInfo(Map<String, String> projectRec, String id) {

        logger.info("Inside updateProjectInfo() API in ProjectServiceImpl");

        Project dbRec = projectRepository.findOne(id);

        setAttributesfromMaptoDBRec(projectRec, dbRec);

        Project updatedProjectRec = null;

        logger.info(" Leaving updateProjectInfo() API in ProjectServiceImpl");

        return updatedProjectRec;
    }

private void setAttributesfromMaptoDBRec(Map<String, String> updatedProjectRecMap, Project updatedProjectRec) {

        logger.info(" Inside setAttributesfromMaptoDBRec() API in ProjectServiceImpl");

        Set<String> nonUpdateableAttributes = ProjectServiceImpl.nonUpdateableKeys.get(ProjectServiceImpl.nonUpdateable);

        if(updatedProjectRecMap == null) {
            logger.warn(" Input Map to service is null in ProjectServiceImpl ===> " + (updatedProjectRecMap == null));
            return;
        }

        for(String key: updatedProjectRecMap.keySet()) {

            logger.info(" Project property ===>  " + key);

            logger.info(" nonUpdateableAttributes contains key  ===> " + nonUpdateableAttributes.contains(key));

            if(!nonUpdateableAttributes.contains(key)) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Field name: " + updatedProjectRec.getClass().getField(key));
                    System.out.println("HOW TO AUTOMATICALLY SET THE ATTRIBUTE TO THE POJO CLASS BASED ON THE KEY ??");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: If keys in map are the same as properties names of POJO you can try to use reflection

Comment: I have done it quiet a long before using Jackson objectMapper.readObject & writeObject.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar thing long back using Jackson databind API. 
Not sure, but this may be helpful:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ObjectMarshalUtility {

    public static <T> Map marshalObject(T obj){
        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        oMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return oMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
    }

    public static <T> T unMarshalObject(Class<T> classType, Map<String, Object> map){
        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        oMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return oMapper.convertValue(map, classType);
    }
}
```

For converting a DTO to a MAP:

```
Map<String,Object> searchInputMap=ObjectMarshalUtility.marshalObject(searchInputDTO);
```

For converting a Map to a DTO:

```
SearchInputDTO searchInputDTO=ObjectMarshalUtility.unMarshalObject(searchInputMap);
```